# url in StreamReader

Tags: c#, combobox, streamreader

when i use this code,i can see text file in the folder That named like one of combobox item.

and when i change this **@"C:\xampp\htdocs\c\"** to *http://localhost:81/c/*
is not work and show this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: URI formats are not supported.

what can i do ?

```
private void toolStripComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    richTextBox1.Text = toolStripComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string rich =  toolStripComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                richTextBox1.Text= rich += ".txt";

           StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(@"C:\xampp\htdocs\c\" + rich);
                       richTextBox1.Text = rd.ReadToEnd();     
                           rd.Close();
```

sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: You can not use URIs in a StreamReader...

Comment: @Pikoh thanks but what i can instead use URIs in a StreamReader ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use WebClient to read files from server ;

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://localhost:81/c/"+ rich);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string str= reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: thanks for answer,but i want see text inside the text file

Comment: you just need to set text to str

Answer (score 0):

i add this code  to **Nihat Mert** answer and its work

```
 richTextBox1.Text = str;
```